# SQL Server 2008 R2: Cursor with condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I have the table which contains the table's id and name.

Now I want to retrieve the table names by passing table ID to the stored procedure.

**Example**:

```
create procedure spGetAllTables
@TableIDs varchar(max)

AS

DECLARE @Tables varchar(max)

    DECLARE Cur1 CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT TableName FROM TablesContainer
    WHERE TableID IN (@TableIDs)

    OPEN Cur1
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @Tables
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT(@Tables)
        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @Tables

    END

    CLOSE Cur1;

    DEALLOCATE Cur1;

GO
```

**Explanation**: The table `TablesContainer` contains all table's ID's and table's names. I just want to print all those table names which I have passed their table ID's to the stored procedure.

The procedure working fine if I pass single value to the variable `@TableIDs`. **But** If I pass multiple values like `1,2,3` to `@TableIDs` then its not getting entered into the `cursor`.

Comment: You have to use a split function or dynamic sql to handle comma-separated IDs.

Comment: That's because variables are scalar. They do not magically make your query run as dynamic sql. The bigger question is why do you need a cursor here?

Comment: @TabAlleman, Okay. I am trying to solve this by using Dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange, If you know the better way then please proceed.

Comment: This seems like homework or just for learning because the real world implications of this code are totally elusive. You need to stop thinking row by row. There is no need for a cursor here. You just to split the string. Here is an article with a number of ways to split strings. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: The better way is to use a separate table instead of storing a comma-delimited list of values. A separate table can have indexes, be used in relations and queries while a CSV field can't. In any case, there are a lot of ways to split a string and the link posted by SeanLange covers them all.

Comment: What is the schema of `TableContainer`? If it's a many-to-many table, splitting isn't required at all. You could simply write an `IN (...)` query or pass a table-valued parameter with the list of IDs, then join the TVP to `TableContainer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you don't need cursor, there is multiple way to separate string you can pass `table value parameter` and `split the string` but as per the Q requirement [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/)

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Id INT)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1),(2),(6)

DECLARE @TableIDs  varchar(max),
        @xml xml

SELECT @TableIDs = '1,2,3,4,5'
SELECT @xml = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <x>' + REPLACE(@TableIDs,',','</x> <x>') + '</x>   </root> ')


SELECT id FROM @temp
WHERE id IN (
SELECT  T.c.value('.','INT')
        FROM @xml.nodes('/root/x') T(c)     
)
```

Comment: Still getting nothing in output.

Comment: @MAK what is the error it is working for me see my updated answer

Comment: The ID is in GUID format. Is that is the problem for this?

Comment: @then convert into `INT` to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`

Comment: Yup! Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: There's no need to split the string at all, the OP can pass a table valued parameter with the IDs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes agree sir !

Answer (score 1):

You don't neet to pass the IDs as a CSV list. SQL Server has [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) since the SQL Server 2008 version at least. A TVP is a table parameter to which you insert data with plain INSERT statements in SQL, or as an collection (a  DataTable or DataReader) in ADO.NET.

You can JOIN with the TVP as you would with any table or table variable.

First, you need to define the TVP type in the database:

```
CREATE TYPE IdTableType AS TABLE ( ID uniqueidentifier);
```

Then you can write a stored procedure to use it:

```
create procedure spGetAllTables(@TableIDs IdTableType READONLY)
AS
    SELECT TableName 
    FROM TablesContainer
    inner join @TableIDs on @TableIDs.ID=TablesContainer.TableID
```

To call the stored procedure from T-SQL you can create a table parameter and fill it:

```
declare @tableIds IdTableType;

insert into @tableIds 
VALUES
('....'),
('....');

exec @spGetAllTables(@tableIds);
```

Comment: 1Plus! Thank you so much.